# What does it mean to say "the inequality is tight up to constant factors"?

Tags: inequality, notation, definition, constants

On the [Wikipedia page for Pinsker's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality), it states "the inequality is tight up to constant factors".

$$
\delta(P, Q) \leq \sqrt{\frac 1 2 D_\text{KL}(P||Q)}
$$

What does this mean?  Surely any inequality could be made tight by adding a constant factor (assuming the minimum of the ratio of the two sides exists).

Comment: Have you looked at the source for this statement at Wikipedia? In Exercise 3.18 in the book referenced, this is explained.

Comment: I did, and I thought I understood the concept, but it seems to me that all inequalities are tight up to a constant factor.  From what I understand, $a \leq C b$ is tight $\iff \inf(b/a) = C\ \ \forall a, b$.  Is that correct?  So tight means that the infimum of the ratio between the functions is the same regardless of the functions?  As opposed to an inequality where, given certain functions, the infimum of the ratio is unbounded?

Comment: Perhaps this is due to the base of the logarithm used in KL divergence? The above statement of Pinsker's inequality assumes natural logarithm is used. Another base would impute a different constant factor.